# Which table does processmaker get the passwords from?

Tags: php, mysql, processmaker

I am integrating PM with a custom laravel application and I am using the USER table from PM to authenticate users. I am now at the point where I want to reset passwords and I tried changing the USR_PASSWORD value in USER table with a md5 string but no luck. I can still log in with old password and not with the new one. It seems it doesn't use that value. But I cannot figure out which one it uses. Does anyone know which table does process maker gets the passwords for the users from?

Comment: Hello! Why not use Processmaker Rest API? There is a endpoint for users management. You must check in the wiki [link](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/REST_API_Administration)

Comment: I do use the API. I find it inconsistent and buggy. And there is no password reset API endpoint which is sad.

Answer (score 2):

They use RBAC_USERS table for the password. I don't understand why they do that or why they even have a USR_PASSWORD field in the USER table if it is not being used. PM can be such a pain to work with at times.